# What function to use for fitting the graph of velocity vs time for f1 car in a curve?

Tags: correlation-functions

I am helping an IB student fit a curve.
We are doing an analysis of F1 in a curve, graphing it velocity vs time.

[image]

Any idea what function could I use. In the refference video we used, the guy uses geogebra and fitts the plot in two parts in two different functions. Onw for the first flat part with drop and the second wiith the curve. I was thinking it would be better if we could fit it with one function than use it to analyse and optimize the data, also using origin or mathlab.
Help?